# How to call a method asynchronously in a normal method in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have an action result in mvc.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod()
{
   return json(somethod());
}
```

Now i have one void method(MethodB),and i want to call this method asynchronously in MYMethod().

```
Public void MethodB()
{
    //some logic 
}
```

I tried calling like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod()
{
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { MethodB(); });
   return json(somethod());
}
```

But unable to achieve asynchronous functionality.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.
PS. I am calling my ActionResult(MyMethod) from jquery. Is it stopping asynchronous.

Comment: *But unable to achieve asynchronous functionality.* What does that mean?

Comment: its not calling asynchronously

Comment: You have another call to `somethod` which is fired synchronously.